# API Versioning - What do I do if model changes

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, swagger

I'm fairly new with APIs and versioning but from what I understand, the developer (which is me) should retain the code if there will be a contract breaking change for the API. Correct me if I'm wrong but I consider Model changes as contract breaking change.

So my question is - Do you make a new model (ex. ModelName.V2) just for the sake of versioning? Is there a better way to do this? This would mean even a slight change in property in my model would mean I would iterate it to another version.

p.s. let me know if I need to edit my question as I'm also fairly new in StackOverflow.

Sample

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

and accompanying Controller

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]/[action]")]
public class Products : Controller
{
   Product[] prod = new Product[]{
       new Product(){ID = 1, Name = "T-Shirt"},
       new Product(){ID = 2, Name = "Jeans"}
   };


   [HttpGet]
   [ActionName("gotcha")]
   public IActionResult GetProduct()
   {
       return Ok(prod);  
   }
}
```

and for V2 Controller

```
[ApiVersion("2.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]/[action]")]
public class V2.Products : Controller
{
       [HttpGet]
       [ActionName("gotcha")]
       public IActionResult GetProduct()
       {
           var trash = "Hello World!";
           return OK(trash);  
       }
}
```

The above codes are what I understand as contract breaking and needed versioning and below is my problem with Model contract breakage:

```
public class Product
{
   public int ID {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public decimal Price {get;set;}
}
```

So the sample above shows I added a new property. This I consider as contract breakage and do I iterate a new controller version and then retain the old Model as well? In the future this will be messy if I keep legacy versions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you only need to reversion if there's a *breaking* change. Not everything is necessarily a breaking change, and typically adding a new property is not in fact a breaking change. Outdated clients should simply ignore it, and if not, that's more on the client than you, as they'd be doing something weird/wrong to cause anything to break that way. You need to be more concerned about changes or deletions, which from a client perspective are kind of the same thing; with a change, it's as if the old property was removed and new one was added. Even then, though, it only matters if the name or the type changes. Any under the hood processing doesn't matter, and technically, even if you change the property name, you can utilize something like the `JsonProperty` attribute to make the serialization return the old name, if you want.

Assuming you *do* have a breaking change, then yes, you should create a new version of your model class, and probably a new action/controller to go with it, both named with the new version number, i.e. `Product2` and `GetProduct2` and/or `Product2Controller`, etc. Yes, this can lead to code duplication, but there's two things you can do to minimize that:

1. Use inheritance if possible. For example, `Product2` can inherit from `Product` and simply override whatever property needs to change. If you just add a new `GetProduct2` action, you can factor out the original code for `GetProduct` into a private generic method `GetProduct2<TProduct>`, and then reimplement the original (and new) method to simply return that, i.e. `return GetProduct<Product>();` and `return`GetProduct();`. These are just examples. There's many different ways to handle this, but the point is that it doesn't necessarily require major code duplication to do versioning.
2. If you notice your codebase is starting to feel cluttered, you can begin deprecating API versions. Issue a notice to your clients that one or more of your oldest versions are now deprecated. Then, after a reasonable amount of time (depending on the complexity of the changes required to get up to date), remove that old code in a new release. This will of course break any outdated clients, but they were forewarned and given time to change, so if they don't that's on them. You'll notice all the big boys do this from time to time. I know I've been receiving a ton of emails from Facebook warning of pending API version removals. That's essentially what they're doing behind the scenes: cleaning their codebase.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

When I do a API versioning. I add a new model with the Version number just to be able to track down the changes in data data structure, example:

```
public class ProductV2
{
        //New attributes
}
```

I would just inherit attributes from the previous version, if the new model is similar to the old one plus new attributes:

```
public class ProductV2 : Product
{
        //New attributes
}
```

Hopefully I understood your question this time.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I think you missed  the point of my question. I've added a code sample to clarify things up.

Comment: @Boxed what Phael suggested should work for your problem, just create a ProductV2 class extending Product and add price as the new field in ProductV2